# Ember JS Route old data briefly visible before new data loads

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My issue is that when a user goes to my route book/:id/:version, it takes some time to pull the JSON and for a quick second it still renders the old data then replaces it with the new data.

This is my route:

```
App.BookRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, model) {

        // This gets the entire JSON for the single book
        Ember.$.getJSON('/book?id=' + model.id + '&version=' + model.version,
            function (data) {

                // Set the json to the model
                controller.set('model', data);

            });

    }
});
```

This is my Router:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    // Homepage (All the books)
    this.resource('index', { path: '/' });


    // Single Book view
    this.resource('book', { path: '/book/:id/:version' });

});
```

So for example, on the first visit to #/book/2/1, it works fine.  The next visit to another book #/book/3/1, it will show the data (the html template rendered) for #/book/2/1 for a quick second and then load the data for #/book/3/1.

How do I clear the view after the user leaves? Or how do I make it not show the previously loaded book in the route/view.

Thanks.

**Edit (Added a possible relevant issue):**

Also I have another issue that may or may not be related, but the didInsertElement event is called before the actual HTML is rendered to the DOM.  I thought this method is called after the HTML is rendered to the DOM.

This is the view:

```
App.BookView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function () {
        console.log('inside didInsertElement');
    }
});
```

Comment: How are you navigating to the route?  I assume you're sending in a dummy model with the `book_id` and `version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it's because you're doing that in your setup controller hook. Getting data like that should be done in your model hook. This guide tells you how to do it refer to the "Dynamic Routes" section: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/

Try doing this

```
App.Router.map(function () {
// Homepage (All the books)
   this.resource('index', { path: '/' });


// Single Book view
   this.resource('book', { path: '/book/:book_id/:version' });

});

App.BookRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
  return Ember.$.getJSON('/book?id=' + params.book_id + '&version=' + params.version);
 }
});
```

I actually think that :id as a param is reserved as it's recommended to do something like `:book_id`

Comment: Quote from @alexspeller on irc: "your params in routes definitions should generally be named "/path/:foo_id", the ending in _id is important" So if anything, it's important

Comment: That's only if you aren't using id, or if you don't want to override the default serialize hook.